# Error 500 when exporting to Excel with jett

Tags: java, jett

When I export Excel with jett I get this error. I lost a few days because of it

Maven:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ozlerhakan</groupId>
        <artifactId>poiji</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jett/jett-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jett</groupId>
        <artifactId>jett-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
public <S, T> void exportToExecl(HttpServletResponse response, List<S> listError, String template) {

    try {
        Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<>();
        beans.put("excel",listError);

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/templates/" + template);
        InputStream fileIn =new BufferedInputStream(resource.getInputStream());

        ExcelTransformer transformer = new ExcelTransformer();
        Workbook workbook = transformer.transform(fileIn, beans);

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Erorr_" + template);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        workbook.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new InfoCityException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        throw new InfoCityException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Message Error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-04-22T03:44:01.120+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "'int org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()'"
}
```

Comment: If I use version 3.14 I can't use poiji. Is there a way to use both, or how can I fix the other error? Thanks everyone

Comment: No, there's no solution. JETT 0.11.0 must use POI 3.14.  We eventually patched JETT to be able to use Apache POI 3.18, but I'm not aware of any way to use POI 5.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned in your comment, the problem is that you're using Apache POI 5.0 whereas JETT 0.11.0 requires POI 3.14 to run.

There was discussions on the JETT forum to fork it in order to support latest POI versions, but nothing happened as far as I know.